# Prevent horizontal scroll without hiding overflow on body

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox

I've got a large element (in this case an image, but it could be any DOM element), that is flowing over the right side of the screen and overlaps both the header element and the one below it, being sized 125% the height of its parent. I can prevent the horizontal scroll with `overflow-x: hidden` on the body/html, but when reloading the page the scroll position is reset. Is there any way around this?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2om58vw7/

[image]

Comment: how do you mean scrolls back to top? what do you actually want it to do when you reload the page?

Comment: Do you want child of .header to be fit with in that .header ? Because you are trying to prevent overflow and avoiding scroll bar .Hence it is displaying full

Comment: @MarkoMackic Normal behavior is that when you reload the scroll position is saved. However, when overflow is hidden on body/html, this is prevented.

Comment: and overflow on .over-container ? https://jsfiddle.net/2om58vw7/1/

Comment: @NagaSaiA No, I want .over positioned exactly like it is in the image, but without scrollbars and without the scroll position being reset. It would be quite simple if it didn't need to go off the side of the screen.

Comment: @GCyrillus That won't work because it cuts of the bottom of .over, which needs to remain visible.

Comment: what about using js solution to store scrolling position, and restore after reload ? and can you confirm this issue on your local browsers ( more of them )

Comment: Not sure....if this works for you http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RRGPBZ

i ahve reduced the width and height to get better understanding of the issue.Green colored one is the child element in the example in codepen

Comment: @NagaSaiA Yes, essentially that, but with the red, black and yellow divs filling the full screen width.

Comment: @MarkoMackic Sure, a JS solution is one option, but I was hoping to be able to do it with pure CSS. Seems like there should be a way. What do you mean can I confirm it?

Comment: Well I mean only have you tested that bug with more than one browser :)

Comment: @MarkoMackic Yes, it isn't browser related.

Comment: I think that if you need it now use js, but if you can wait, maybe answer will come in pure css. It's interesting problem thought.

Comment: @JamesSimpson. What effect are you trying to achieve that needs you to have the element out of the viewport? Is it a specific image position? Is it to accommodate different screen sizes? I notest that you are using `width`in a flex element and as a best practice you should use `flex`unless you need a `max/min-width`...Or is it an undesirable side effect?

Comment: @PauloJaneiro It is to accommodate different screen sizes. The width is the max width of the SVG, and then it scales down based on the size of the parent. As per the design, it sits on the right side of the screen, and only fully shows within the viewport if the screen width is wide enough. On most viewports it would show only part of the image., with the rest being cut off the screen.